# Python creating array of permutations with conditions on pool of values at each level of the array

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

Conceptually I am trying to build the arrays of permutations possible from a pool of 10 values ex.[0-9] where you have a choice of 3 at each element based on a ranking. So say the first element chosen was 0 then next possible pool of values to choose from would be 1,2,3. If three was then chosen [0,3] then next choice would have a pool of [1,2,4] and so on. I would like this for 5 levels but of course was trying to code a solution that was arbitrary to the number of levels, values and limiting condition. 
The goal is the have all permutations passed back in an nested array. I will be using this array to build a DataFrame for a visualization.

My first attempt was creating all permutations for the 10 values using `itertools permutations` then remove from that those that would not fit my condition based on distance from the preceding entry. This seemed inefficient but I also had a hard time nailing down the condition for removal.

edit: I did not correctly specify that the selection process always starts with [0,1,2] as the first choices. Additional choices are added in at each level according to the next rank available up the max rank of say 10. So if 2 is chosen at the first level, then '3' comes in to take its place. [0,1,3] are next choices available. If 1 then chosen you have [0,3,4] at next level to choose from. This continues until you hit the max length of say 5 choices made.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how your selection generally works. If `8` was chosen first, what would be the next pool? And how exactly does the pool change after a second number is selected?

Comment: Can you clarify? Can the first chosen element of a permutation be any of 0 to 9, or can it only be drawn from an initial pool of [0, 1, 2]? Does a complete permutation have all 10 values or can each permutation be of variable length? It's not clear how to extend your examples to a complete specification of the behaviour you intend.

Comment: I added some clarification. Let me know more is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if I understand correctly, this is the process you're describing:

```
Reserve: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Pool: [0, 1, 2]
Chosen: []
```

So long as we do not yet have 5 `Chosen` items, remove any item from the `Pool` and append it to the chosen sequence. Then remove the *first* item from `Reserve` and append it to the pool. Repeat as necessary.

I'm going to use *P* for the size of the pool and *N* for the length of a chosen sequence. So P=3 and N=5 in this example.

I'm still a bit unsure if this is the process you intend to describe, as it seems 7, 8 and 9 can never appear in the chosen sequence, but you do say you are trying to come up with a general solution, so I'll assume that "reserve" is in fact of unlimited size.

And your question is, how do we enumerate all of the possible chosen sequences?

The only choice that you get to make during this process is which element to draw out of the pool. You always have P (=3) choices. Those choices will *always* be different items (since there's only one of each item). So long as you are convinced that there are not two different sequences of choices that could result in the same sequence of items, you can see now that you have exactly P<sup>N</sup> possible sequences. The only tricky thing remaining is to convert a sequence of choice indexes into a sequence of choice values. In lieu of doing anything clever, I propose simply executing the algorithm we described above.

```py
from itertools import (product, count)

def generate_sequences(pool_size, n):
    for choice_sequence in product(range(pool_size), repeat=n):
        pool = list(range(pool_size))
        sequence = []
        reserve = count(pool_size)
        for choice_index in choice_sequence:
            sequence.append(pool[choice_index])
            pool[choice_index] = next(reserve)
        yield sequence
```

I think this works. To simplify matters instead of deleting a chosen item from the middle of the pool and appending the new item from the reserve on the end of the pool, I'm putting the new item into the slot vacated by the chosen item. This changes the order we emit the sequences but I think it shouldn't change the overall set of sequences generated.

There might well be a simpler way to do this but I think this is about as good as it gets in terms of time complexity.

---

Unaddressed here is whether the base set of items (let's call its size R) might be limited. Clearly it must be the case that R ≥ N or you are simply unable to select N items at all. However if R < P + N − 1 then you *can* select N items but it isn't possible to maintain a constant pool of size P - eventually you have no items in the reserve to add to it. That's surmountable but fiddly. I'll leave that as an exercise.